# How can I match a certain string with a regex?

Tags: regex

The following string is repeated several times in a file. Each line starts with  `https` and ends with `td>`. The lines are separated by other strings and \n:

```
https://xxxxxxtd>
paila
paila
https://xxxxxxtd>
paila
https://xxxxxxtd>
https://xxxxxxtd>
```

I would like to match all strings in that example that start with `https` and end with `td>` using a regular expression.
I have written the following regular expression and tested it in: https://regex101.com/ but it won't work:

```
^ht((.|\n)*)td\>$
```

What is it missing?

Comment: is this sentence at the start or at the end of a line? Does it contain whitespace characters?

Comment: You'll get a better response if you provide some more concrete examples of what you do and don't want it to match, but my guess is that changing the `*` to `*?` will do the trick.

Answer (score 4):

You don't have to escape the closing angle bracket that isn't a special character.

If you do it the sequence `\>` is seen as a closing word boundary *(that matches at the end of a word)* and the `$` anchor would fail since the literal `>` isn't consumed.

```
^https.*td>$
```

should work.